# Non-compact surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

A subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is called *compact* if it is closed (i.e., the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that are not in $X$ is open) and *bounded* (i.e., $X$ is contained in some open ball). 
If $S$ is a surface, then the surface is compact iff $S$ is compact.

Why is the Möbius strip not a compact surface? Can you give me another example of a limited non-compact surface with boundary?

Comment: If the Möbius strip is not compact, it must be because the edge is not included in the set we're considering. _With_ the boundary, any reasonable embedding of the Möbius strip in $\mathbb R^3$ should be compact.

Comment: @HenningMakholm is correct, the Möbius strip is compact, unless you are not including the boundary, in which case, the problem with it is that it isn't closed.

Comment: @Henning: Pressley's book "Elementary Differential Geometry" (2ed) says (at page 111, Corollary 5.4.5) that "Every compact surface is orientable"... so the Möbius strip should be not compact. I really don't understand the definition of compact surface cited by the book.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't allow something that includes a boundary to be considered a "surface" in the first place?

Comment: @Henning: yes, I started to believe that it is just as you say. Do you mind if I ask you to write down the definition of surface you get used to? Pressley's is this: "a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a surface if, for every point $p \in S$, there is an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and an open set $W$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing $p$ such that $S \cap W$ is homeomorphic to $U$."

Comment: @Lmn, I'm not a good person to ask about that. I never learned differential geometry formally, so I generally just extrapolate the theory from Wikipedia as I go along. The definition you quote clearly prevents the surface from including a boundary.

Comment: @Lmn6: Note that that is not possible if $S$ is the Mobius strip with boundary and $p$ is a point on the boundary; there is no open set $W\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$ containing $p$ such that $S\cap W$ is homeomorphic to an open set $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Ok, the last two comments (by Henning and Zev) are a lot interesting because now I think I probably understood what is the meaning of "compact surface" in Pressley's book. I believe it's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface#Closed_surfaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can think of a Möbius strip independently of any particular embedding inside $\mathbb{R}^3$, IE just as a two dimensional manifold.  One definition is the set $\mathbb{R} \times [0,1]$ with $(x,0)$ glued to $(-x,1)$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  A bunch of copies of $\mathbb{R}$, one for each element of $[0,1]$, glued to together at the ends with a reversing twist, if you will.  Let $M$ be the Möbius strip defined this way.  The first nice property of this definition is that every point is the same in the sense that, 'locally' everything looks like $\mathbb{R}^2$.

In the construction above you can use an open interval $(-1,1)$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$. But if you use a closed interval $[-1,1]$ as an alternate definition you don't really have a Möbius strip, but a related object, a 'manifold with boundary'. These aren't quite so nice: nearby every point it may look like $\mathbb{R}^2$, or for boundary points it may look like the closed upper half plane.  Manifolds with boundary are not as easy to work with.

The Möbius strip is a good first example of a (non-trivial) vector bundle.  Another example is the cylinder, which is what you get from same construction above, but **without** the twist.  While the cylinder is a vector bundle, it is a trivial one: it's essentially just the Cartesian product of a circle with a vector space (the real number line).

For a better info on vector bundles see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle.

Comment: How do the smooth functions $M\to\mathbb R$ fail to form a vector space?

Comment: Also, in a vector bundle, the vector spaces don't overlap at all - they partition the total space.

Comment: Yes, of course HM and JD, thanks.

Comment: Even with the edit, I still have to mildly object.  The word "trivial" for vector bundle almost never means "just a vector space, taken as a whole" because the base space almost never has the structure of a vector space in a compatible fashion.  If you want "trivial" to mean this, then an easier example of a "nontrivial" bundle is the trivial vector bundle over 2 points.  The Mobius band is an example of a nontrivial bundle in the sense that it's not bundle isomorphic to a product $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$ even though locally it is.

Comment: My objection is unchanged. The answer still claims that the smooth functions from $M$ to $\mathbb R$ do not form a vector space, which is just wrong. The pointwise sum of two such functions is itself a smooth function; the scaling of a smooth function by any real number is also a smooth function. That makes them a vector space.

Comment: I think I finally fixed it... now that it's just archival.  :)

Answer (score 7):

The Möbius strip *without boundary*, i.e. without its edge, is not compact. Similarly, the cylinder
$$\mathbb{S}^1\times(0,1)=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid x^2+y^2=1,\;\;0<z<1\}$$
is a bounded non-compact surface. This is because, without their boundaries, these subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are not closed. With their boundaries, both of these surfaces *are* closed, and hence compact, e.g.
$$\mathbb{S}^1\times[0,1]=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid x^2+y^2=1,\;\;0\leq z\leq 1\}$$
is compact.

By the way, it is a *theorem* (the [Heine-Borel theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)) that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded; where compact has [this more general meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space).

Comment: Can I ask you what is the exact definition of surface you are using? Thanks

Comment: Since you are asking about $\mathbb{R}^3$, I mean a 2-dimensional [embedded submanifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold) of $\mathbb{R}^3$. One can also define "surface" without reference to an [ambient space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_space), by simply declaring that a surface is a 2-dimensional [manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold). See [the wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface) for more explanation.